# Not following turns following whenever users push the button, and vice versa

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Now I am trying to add follow button to my users' index page.

My goal is like...
when users push the button once, the message beside the button turns "following". And he or she push it again, the message turns "not following". Default message is "not following".

And then I wrote the codes below.

☆index.html.erb(members_controller)

```
<% @members.each do |member| %>
   <td>
        <div class="onoff">
            <% unless session[:user_id] == member.id %>
             <%= link_to'on/off', {:controller => 'members', :action => 'index', :id =>
                  member.id}, class: "btn btn-midium btn-primary"%><br/>

               <% if @isFr %>
                  ※following
               <% else %>
                  ※not following
               <% end %>
             <% end %>  
         </div>
    </td>
```

☆members_controller

```
def index

 @members = Member.where("id >=1").order("created_at desc").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10).scoped
    if Friend.where(:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id => params[:id]).exists? then
       Friend.where(:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id => params[:id]).each do |f|
        f.destroy
        end
    else
       Friend.new({:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id =>params[:id].to_i}).save
    end


      @members.each do |m|
      @isFr = Friend.where(:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id => 
      m.id ).count > 0  
      end 
end
```

As a result, .save and .destroy works. but when I push a button of a member, the messages for the other members also turn to "following". I don't want it to do so.I would like to change the message of the member who I push the button.Just one person.

How can I solve this? I really appreciate it if you could give me some advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the value of @isFr variable in each iteration. You'll have to use some data structure to store the required info. 
For example:

```
@isFr = {}
@members.each do |m|
  @isFr[m.id] = Friend.where(:member_id => session[:user_id], :friend_id => m.id ).count > 0  
end
```

Then in your view you can check if user is following a member as follows:

```
<% @members.each do |member| %>
   <td>
        <div class="onoff">
            <% unless session[:user_id] == member.id %>
             <%= link_to'on/off', {:controller => 'members', :action => 'index', :id =>
                  member.id}, class: "btn btn-midium btn-primary"%><br/>

               <% if @isFr[member.id] %>
                  ※following
               <% else %>
                  ※not following
               <% end %>
             <% end %>  
         </div>
    </td>
<% end %>
```

---

Also,

1. Instead of `Friend.new(...).save` you could also use
   `Friend.create()`
2. You should probably separate the on/off logic in
   another action and then redirect to index action after you are done with .save /
   .destroy